# Can I add information to a CP new entries page?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, routes, routing

I would like to add a google map in an entry edit page for certain entry types.

I already have a plugin started to go and grab the lat and long for the entered address.  What I'm now trying to achieve is to add the map to the admin page. I'd like to put it in the right pane.

I have looked at `hookRegisterCpRoutes()` but I don't think it's possible to override pre-existing routes.

Is their a way to achieve my goal or my plugin should be taking care of the entire entry type instead ?

Comment: Hi Eric... Not sure how far into this plugin development you are, but there are already a couple great Google Map plugins out there. Perhaps one of those would make a better starting point for what you are trying to achieve? Either [Smart Map](https://craftpl.us/plugins/smart-map) or [Google Maps for Craft](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Google-Maps-for-Craft) may help speed up your process.

Comment: Thanks Lindsey.  I will download them to at least look at how they are built.  The google map I need is ultra simple and I'm trying to migrate a Wordpress site  to Craft and I want it to be as identical as possible.  At the same time, I'm learning the plugin structure and all that.  Since this is more of a learning project, I'm trying to build everything from scratch.  I have to say that I'm impressed at how easy it's been until I got into the plugins part.